# Rails generate failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

After a while, I was in the way to implement a new functionality in my app. When I try to generate an scaffold or access the console, this is what I get back:

[image: rails]

I have tried to stop spring, to update the bundle.. but nothing. What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try to run `spring stop` before running the generator?

Comment: Try removing and re-installing the rails gem?  Possible corruption?

Comment: So far, I made it work removing spring libraries, but this is not a solution. It seems some problem of incompatibility with Ruby 2.6

Answer (score 0):

You could try forcing it to use the bundle by adding `bundle exec` in front of your `rails g ...` call.

Comment: That doesn't work. It seems a matter of incompatibilities with current version of Ruby